# Trouble with appending a href with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, append

Using HTML, `<a href=#>1</a>` will lead me back to current page, but when I do it in jQuery, it leads me to the index of localhost. How can I make it work in a similar way to the HTML?

```
$(id).append("<a href='#'> 1 </a>");
```

Comment: What was the resulting HTML after appending?

Comment: It was <a href='#'> 1 </a>, just as written, and it leads to index of localhost...

Comment: Those should be the same. I think your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Wouldn't a single hash just scroll the page to the top ?

Comment: @Jason P - actually they are not. in source code html version looks this way href=CURRENTPAGE# and appended looks like this href=#

Comment: Do you see the same problem in all browsers?

Comment: @andi yes, same in IE, Opera, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Works as expected for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/FYDPJ/1/

Comment: Still cant make it work :(

Comment: So, do you have any click handlers on your website? Also, you say "in source code html version looks this way href=CURRENTPAGE#" but how does that happen? The browsers I've tried all keep the `#` intact when viewing the resulting DOM tree.

Comment: Check your console to see if there are any errors.